# Prince of Persia for PC Windows 7

Tags: pc, windows-7, prince-of-persia

my query is if anyone knows where I can download the original Prince of Persia for PC, that works on Windows 7. I had it, but for Windows XP. The other day I tried it on Windows 7 and it didn't work anymore even with compatibility mode.

regards,
Thank you

Comment: Idk if they have the original but [gog.com](https://www.gog.com/) has 4 of the PoP games. Ive never  played any of them so idk if any of them are indeed the original.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install/run 16-bit games on Win 7 32-bit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158874/is-it-possible-to-install-run-16-bit-games-on-win-7-32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the 1989 game [Prince of Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)) failed to run?

I do not think there are multiple versions of this game for PC out there.  This is a 16-bit DOS game. It's likely your Windows-7 installation is the 64-bit edition on a 64-bit machine, while the windows-XP installation was 32-bit software (which may or may not have been on a 64-bit cpu).

The transition to 64-bit has broken certain aspects of compatibility with old 16-bit applications. Most games from the 16-bit era are troublesome to natively run on windows.

Luckily for you, almost all such games were not actually written for windows<sup>note</sup>: Instead, devs cut out the middleman and wrote directly for the underlying operating system: DOS. And we have some very good emulators available for this. Have you tried running the game using [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/)?

note: At the time, windows had poor game support, and the hardware was too slow to share resources between the desktop and the game.

Comment: Yes, exactly I mean the 1989 version (that year it came out for the Apple II), I think in 1990 it came out for DOS PCs.
my version of windows 7 is 32 bit and it gives error. In Windows XP it worked.
I have never used DOSBox, I will try it.

Thank you.

Comment: After having had his perfectly timed Karateka Re-Coded to other OS, Prince of Persia was written so lean and pedantically commented that porting it from the native **Apple II** it was written on and for to any other OS was a piece of cake, Jordan Mechner says.